# How do i create this custom UI in iOS

Tags: ios

I'm basically an Android programmer and on my way to learning some skills on iOS platform.

I have an Android application, which has a custom UI component which looks like

[image: this].

I want to create a similar re-usable UI component for my sample iOS application. I'm not able to get any lead on how to do this in iOS.

On Android I can create a composite UI element using a layout file but in iOS i'm not sure if i can create a composite UI element or extend UIView and then somehow layout Text and image components inside it.

I'm looking for some leads on implementing this. I plan to have a multiple instances of these component on screen & the values gets updated from a web service.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend something called interface builder in iOS.

It is a place where you can visually place elements that the user interacts with and you can see how the design looks as you layout your structure.

For tutorials, you can look at http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/interface-builder/
or search up "ios xib tutorial"

Hope this helped!

Comment: After going through the book, my impression of IB was that, it is used to create layout for whole application window. I was not sure if i can use it to create a reusable UI component.

Comment: That is where you are fortunately mistaken! :) The IB can be used to build anything from UITableViewCells, custon subviews for image views, custom gestures on views and whole lots more. All you need to do is choose the right class to subclass from! Honestly, it's become an invaluable tool for me when I need to customize something quickly while keeping the design neat! :)

Comment: @prashant,  no, you can use *Interface Builder* (now part of Xcode) to create small, reusable views, too.  In the Inspector properties, you just set the size to `freeform` and then specify the point size (width and height) that you want.  Then, you'll have something that's not full screen.

Comment: Thanks guys for your response. Something to do tonight.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be a simple view, then you could create a UIView sub-class with a few UITextFields's and probably an UIImageView or two that all have outlets so that your controller can make changes to it.  For instance:

```
@interface StockInfo <UIView>

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UITextField *ticker;
// You may want to make these numbers so that you can do calculations with them, and then update the text field automatically
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UITextField *price;  
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UITextField *priceChange;
// This could be automatically calculated based on the price and priceChange if appropriate
// It could also automatically show the Up or Down indicator
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UITextField *percentChange;

@end
```

Then, your controller could create an instance and set the various properties:

```
StockInfo *djia = [[StockInfo alloc] init];
djia.ticker = @"DJIA";
djia.price = @"14550.35" ;
djia.priceChange = @"-111.66";
// ...
```

You can create the actual UI elements within the view either in Interface Builder, or do it in code.  Which to do is kind of a personal preference.  There are plusses and minuses to both, and building the view in code in this case would be pretty easy and not require you to have two files in order to use the control.

Comment: But in this approach, how do i achieve rounded corners and position of the UI elements?

Comment: By "this approach" do you mean if not using IB?  Oddly enough, you can't round the corners in IB at all, so it needs to be done programmatically anyway.  A simple search here on SO will show you how to do that.  You position the UI elements by setting their frame, either when you create them (using `UIView *myNewView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame];`) or by setting the frame property after creating them.